# How do i add a new resource identifier for a drawable in an app decompiled by apktool?

Tags: android, android-drawable, android-resources, smali

I'm trying to inject a imageview in to a decompiled apk's smali code. But the drawable used by the imageview needs it's own unique resource identifier. So far i have been unsuccessful in adding a new resource identifier without getting building  errors from apktool. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Here are the steps i have taken:

**Step 1:**

Find the last resource id in the public.xml file.
In my case : `<public type="menu" name="search_item_minioverflow" id="0x7f0d0003" />`.

Convert the id from hex to text, this gives me the following: *2131558403*.
Increment the number by 1 and convert it back to hex : *0x7f0d0004*.

**Step 2:**

Paste the new resource with incremented id: `<public type="drawable" name="cross" id="0x7f0d0004" />` in to the public.xml file.

**Step 3:**

Paste the new static field with incremented id: `.field public static final cross:I = 0x7f0d0004` in to the R$drawable.smali file.

**Finally:**

I try to build the decompiled apk with apktool but receive the following building error:

```
res\values\public.xml:986: error: Public resource drawable/cross has conflicting type codes for its public identifiers (0x2 vs 0xd).
    W:
    brut.androlib.AndrolibException: brut.common.BrutException: could not exec (exit code = 1): [C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp\brut_util_Jar_6742820997882567173.tmp, p, --forced-package-id, 127, --min-sdk-version, 14, --target-sdk-version, 25, --version-code, 111, --version-name, 5.2.1, --no-version-vectors, -F, C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp\APKTOOL3513689331380739071.tmp, -0, arsc, -0, png, -0, arsc, -I, C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp\1.apk, -S, C:\Users\user\Desktop\tune\res, -M, C:\Users\user\Desktop\tune\AndroidManifest.xml]
```

**EDIT:** And here is the smali code being injected, it runs normally in the apk it's taken from:

```
.method public showDialog()V
    .locals 6

    .line 92
    new-instance v0, Landroid/widget/RelativeLayout;

    invoke-virtual {p0}, Lcom/example/MainActivity;->getApplicationContext()Landroid/content/Context;

    move-result-object v1

    invoke-direct {v0, v1}, Landroid/widget/RelativeLayout;-><init>(Landroid/content/Context;)V

    .line 93
    .local v0, "overlay":Landroid/widget/RelativeLayout;
    new-instance v1, Landroid/widget/RelativeLayout$LayoutParams;

    const/4 v2, -0x1

    invoke-direct {v1, v2, v2}, Landroid/widget/RelativeLayout$LayoutParams;-><init>(II)V

    .line 94
    .local v1, "params":Landroid/widget/RelativeLayout$LayoutParams;
    invoke-virtual {v0, v1}, Landroid/widget/RelativeLayout;->setLayoutParams(Landroid/view/ViewGroup$LayoutParams;)V

    .line 95
    const/4 v2, 0x0

    invoke-virtual {v0, v2}, Landroid/widget/RelativeLayout;->setBackgroundColor(I)V

    .line 96
    invoke-virtual {v0, v2}, Landroid/widget/RelativeLayout;->setClickable(Z)V

    .line 97
    invoke-virtual {v0, v2}, Landroid/widget/RelativeLayout;->setFocusable(Z)V

    .line 99
    new-instance v3, Landroid/widget/ImageView;

    invoke-virtual {p0}, Lcom/example/MainActivity;->getApplicationContext()Landroid/content/Context;

    move-result-object v4

    invoke-direct {v3, v4}, Landroid/widget/ImageView;-><init>(Landroid/content/Context;)V

    .line 100
    .local v3, "cross":Landroid/widget/ImageView;
    const v4, 0x7f060055

    invoke-virtual {v3, v4}, Landroid/widget/ImageView;->setImageResource(I)V

    .line 102
    new-instance v4, Landroid/widget/RelativeLayout$LayoutParams;

    const/4 v5, -0x2

    invoke-direct {v4, v5, v5}, Landroid/widget/RelativeLayout$LayoutParams;-><init>(II)V

    move-object v1, v4

    .line 103
    const/16 v4, 0xb

    invoke-virtual {v1, v4}, Landroid/widget/RelativeLayout$LayoutParams;->addRule(I)V

    .line 104
    invoke-virtual {v3}, Landroid/widget/ImageView;->getDrawable()Landroid/graphics/drawable/Drawable;

    move-result-object v4

    invoke-virtual {v4}, Landroid/graphics/drawable/Drawable;->getIntrinsicHeight()I

    move-result v4

    div-int/lit8 v4, v4, 0x2

    invoke-virtual {v3}, Landroid/widget/ImageView;->getDrawable()Landroid/graphics/drawable/Drawable;

    move-result-object v5

    invoke-virtual {v5}, Landroid/graphics/drawable/Drawable;->getIntrinsicWidth()I

    move-result v5

    div-int/lit8 v5, v5, 0x2

    rsub-int/lit8 v5, v5, 0x50

    invoke-virtual {v1, v2, v4, v5, v2}, Landroid/widget/RelativeLayout$LayoutParams;->setMargins(IIII)V

    .line 105
    invoke-virtual {v3, v1}, Landroid/widget/ImageView;->setLayoutParams(Landroid/view/ViewGroup$LayoutParams;)V

    .line 107
    invoke-virtual {v0, v3}, Landroid/widget/RelativeLayout;->addView(Landroid/view/View;)V

    .line 109
    new-instance v2, Landroid/app/Dialog;

    const v4, 0x1030010

    invoke-direct {v2, p0, v4}, Landroid/app/Dialog;-><init>(Landroid/content/Context;I)V

    .line 110
    .local v2, "topDialog":Landroid/app/Dialog;
    invoke-virtual {v2, v0}, Landroid/app/Dialog;->setContentView(Landroid/view/View;)V

    .line 111
    invoke-virtual {v2}, Landroid/app/Dialog;->show()V

    .line 113
    return-void
.end method
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You're not supposed to find the last resource ID, but the last resource ID of the type you want to add. You incremented 1 to the resource ID of a menu.

You can't just use any resource ID for any resource type. The 3rd and 4th digits of the ID (after the `x`) represent the type. For instance, in your project at least, `0d` is for the menu type, while `02` is for the drawable type.

Instead, look for the last ID of type "drawable" in your public.xml (be careful, they aren't ordered in increasing order) and add 1 to that one instead. It should be `0x7f02xxxx` + 1.

Comment: Yes it's building now! Thank you for the fast response. But my image view is still not being displayed. Are there anymore steps i need to take to create a new resource id? Other views i inject work fine, only the imageview with resource id is giving me trouble.

Comment: I don't see a problem off-the-bat, but you might want to give JADx a try. Compile to an APK and then open that APK in JADx GUI and check the Java result.

Comment: Everything is working fine now, the problem was the injection location of the function call. Thanks again!

Comment: You've saved my life :)))